# closing window without window.open();

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way to close a new tab window that was not opened using `window.open();`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [window opener close issue for javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979696/window-opener-close-issue-for-javascript) (and many others)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. If you didn't open the window you are not supposed to close it.

Comment: i open uses articulate presenter to open the link.., and i want that link to be closed on click event

Answer (score 0):

Please see here: http://www.infimum.dk/HTML/JSwindows.html#ref_3_11

In order to close a specific window using the window.close() method you need a reference to that window, which you can usually get when opening a window using the window.open() method.

Another option I can see is to use global window/frame references (self, parent, opener, etc...You can see the list in the link above as well).