# Closing child window when you close parent window

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to force close a window that is opened from my page but I do not open it myself via window.open()... so I don't have a reference point that I can think of to say windowName.close(); because I never actually open it within my code some other service handles that. I know target="windowName" on the window I want to close but I'm not sure how to tell it to close based on that.

I want to close this window when my main window closes so doing something like:

```
window.onunload = function () {
    windowName.close(); // This does nothing.
};
```

**Question:** How can I close window with attribute target="windowName"?

Comment: You won't be able to unless you have a reference to the child window from `window.open()`

Comment: Can I make a reference to it without making a new window open?

Comment: Check this:- http://thisiswhatiknowabout.blogspot.in/2012/02/how-to-close-child-windows-when-closing.html

Comment: @R.T. he didn't use window.open()

Comment: @johnatrik I don't think so. Instead of trying to close it from the parent, what if you listen for the parent window closing **from the child window**, and close itself?

Comment: The problem is the window opening is from another application that is managed by a different person and he said I will have to close this on my end and supplied me with target="windowStockInventory"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415909/closing-window-without-window-open

Comment: http://www.infimum.dk/HTML/JSwindows.html#ref_2_6

Comment: do you have access to child window's code ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. There is no way to get `window` object by target name. There is no method to get child window list.

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript or jQuery it is impossible to get/close a window only by name.
So You have to use the browser sdk. For instance in Mozilla Firefox you can:

```
var windows = require("sdk/windows");
for each (var window in windows.browserWindows) {
  console.log(window.title);
```

}

to get all opened Windows for the current browser and so decide which one to close.

bye

Answer (score -2):

I think because you're given a frame name you can actually target it and then call close.

Here is the syntax for the target attribute, note that it can take a frame name, which is what you're given I believe.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp

Here is the instruction to how you'd use the frames global array in Javascript, assuming you have the framename.
infimum.dk/HTML/JSwindows.html#ref_2_6

Comment: Is it still a frame if it's in it's own separate tab?

Comment: As I understand it, as long as it was created with the _target attribute, you should be able to, well, target it.  Even if it's in its own separate tab.