# Close window using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, window

I have a window(1) that has a button(1). If I click on the button, then another window(2) will appear. It also has a button(2). If I click on the button (2) then popup will appear. How can I close the window(2) if I press "OK" on the popup window? I am using javascript.

Comment: This question has been answered before. Take a look at this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835549/how-to-communicate-between-two-browser-windows.

Answer (score 1):

```
// store reference to window
var window2 = window.open(...);

// close window via reference, put this in your OK button handler
window2.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

[Read here about window management.](http://www.infimum.dk/HTML/JSwindows.html#ref_2_5)

> You cannot do it according the security assurance of browser, there
>   are some action which doesn't allow to be managed directly via
>   javascript without user interference.

Got this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979696/window-opener-close-issue-for-javascript) /stackoverflow/