# window.close not working in firefox, after using window.open

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm trying to close the present window by clicking a button. I know window.close() could only work when the window is owned by javascript.

---

So I use `window.open()` before, then close that window like:

```
self.name = "close";
window.open("","close");
self.opener = null;
self.close();`
```

---

This works in Chrome and in older versions of Firefox, but not in FF14. 
So how can I close a window in FF14?
thanks!

I run the following javascript in FF console.
It works in IE and Chrome.

```
win=window.open('','_self');
win.close();------undefined
```

Comment: You can close only windows opened using window.open - you can't (by code) close window that opened the pop-up (at least not in every browser). Also check answers to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979696/window-opener-close-issue-for-javascript

Answer (score -1):

Above mentioned comment is right window.close() will work only if the window is opened using window.open().

Try this code:

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:var win = window.open('', '_self');win.close();return false;">Close</a>
```

This is working for me in IE, Chrome and Firefox ( even for FF14). HTH

Comment: I run the following javascript in FF console. IE and chrome will work.but FF will tell me win.close() undefined.

win=window.open('','_self');

win.close();------undefined

Comment: I have checked the above code for the FF 14 and it is working fine at my end. Check the following link: http://codeissue.com/issues/i74ddb15295c601/window-close-does-not-work-in-firefox-and-chrome

Comment: maybe you can check your dom.allow_script_to_close_windows in about:config. I think it's true at your end, but it's false by default, I can't ask end-user to modify this setting.

Comment: dom.allow_scripts_to_close_windows is false. May be you can check in some other PC too for FF 14 whether it is working or not.